# ¿Por qué arroja como resultado "undefined" la última variable del código cuando la trato de imprimir por consola?

Tags: javascript, poo, undefined

- ¿Por qué arroja "undefined" la variable (producto0PrecioConIva) que trato de imprimir por la consola?
- ¿Por qué Visual Studio Code me coloca los 3 puntos como alerta de que "no se ha encontrado el nombre "usuario0" . ¿Quiso decir "Usuarios"? (e igual con los demás objetos instanciados usuario1, 2 y 3) y el código sigue funcionando, si con la función Productos no pasa lo mismo, a pesar de que instancio exactamente igual otros objetos basados en clases ?

Código:

```js
nombre = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre de usuario");

function saludarUsuario(){
    alert("Hola." + nombre + "\n Bienvenido");
   
}

while(nombre == ""){
    alert("Lo siento, debe ingresar un nombre de usuario para continuar.");
    nombre = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre de usuario");
}

saludarUsuario();




class Usuarios{
    constructor(id,nombre,descuento){
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.descuento = descuento;
    }
    
}

usuario0 = new Usuarios(0,nombre,20);
usuario1 = new Usuarios(1,"Bruno Días",20);
usuario2 = new Usuarios(2,"Cosme Fulanito",20);
usuario3 = new Usuarios(3,"Juan Pérez",20);

alert(usuario0.nombre);


class Productos{
    constructor(idProducto,nombreProducto,precio){
        this.idProducto = idProducto;
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    sumarIva(){ 
    this.precio = this.precio * 1.21;
    }
}

producto0 = new Productos(0,"Escudo del Capitán América",5000);
producto1 = new Productos(1,"Disfraz de Superman",8000);
producto2 = new Productos(2,"Disfraz de Ironman",2);
producto3 = new Productos(3,"Disfraz de la Mujer Maravilla",3);

let producto0PrecioConIva = producto0.sumarIva(producto0.precio);
console.log(producto0PrecioConIva + " abc");
```

Comment: no se sobre los erroes en vs code... pero producto0PrecioConIva es undefined porque sumarIva no devuelve nada....

Comment: @gbianchi ¿pero no devuelve nada por qué? ¿no devuelve nada porque no tiene un return o porque no se le está pasando el parámetro adecuadamente?

Comment: porque la funcion no devuelve nada... donde le pusiste que devolviera algo????

Comment: @gbianchi entonces la respuesta sería que la variable producto0PrecioConIva que deseo mostrar por la consola no devuelve nada porque no existe el return en dicho método del objeto (sumarIva), el cual sería la función que interactúa con dicha variable

Comment: aja... que no habias entendido

Comment: la respuesta deberia ser que tu funcion retorne el valor calculado